# Reducer state lost after history.push()

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, state, reducers

**dependencies**

> "react": "^17.0.1" 
> "react-redux": "^7.2.2"

I have a registration page with few steps and each step has a different form. I changed the form based on the segment from the url. So I want to track the step progress by storing it to a reducer but it only work when the first form get loaded (which is default form).

The next step which triggering the `SecondStep` form causing the reducer state to lost after the `history.push()`

**Parent Component**

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import FirstStep from './FirstStep';
import SecondStep from './SecondStep';

export default function Register({
    url
}) {
    const { stepTracker } = useSelector(state => state.registrationReducer)
    const segment = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

    console.log(stepTracker)

    function renderForm(){
        var tpl = (<FirstStep url={url} />)
        if(segment === 'register'){
            tpl = (<FirstStep url={url} />)
        }
        if (segment === 'step2') {
            tpl = (<SecondStep url={url} />)
        }
        return tpl;
    }

    return (
        <div className="section-form highlight">
            <div className="container bg-white container-padding">
                {/* other html code here */}
                <div className="register-form text-center">
                    { renderForm() }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**Child Component - FirstStep**

```
import React from "react";
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { onStepChange } from '../../../redux/actions/registrationActions';

export default function FirstStep({
    url
}) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const history = useHistory()

    function nextStep(){
        dispatch(onStepChange('step2', true));
        history.push(`${url}/step2`)
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            {/* other html code here */}
            <a onClick={()=>nextStep()} className="boxed-btn3 btn-block">Next Step</a>
        </div>
    );
}
```

`console.log(stepTracker)` become `undefined` after `history.push()` get triggered.

Comment: Can you set up a minimal example (maybe in a codesandbox) and share your reducer logic?

Comment: @JosefWittmann Please check the sandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/green-fog-n2bct .It has error in the sandbox but at least you can see the setup. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your reducer logic (only seen in the sandbox, not in the question).

The problem was there:

```js
return {
  ...state.stepTracker,
  [fieldName]: value
};
```

Here is how it works:

```js
return {
  ...state,
  stepTracker: {
    ...state.stepTracker,
    [fieldName]: value
  }
}
```

The reason is, the **`stepTracker` property got replaced** in your reducer state. So initially the reducer state was something like

```js
{
  stepTracker: {
    step1: true,
    step2: false,
    step3: false
  }
}
```

but got transformed to this:

```js
{
  step1: true,
  step2: false,
  step3: false
}
```

Comment: I see. Will try it out first. Thanks! :)